# How to split values in cells for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having trouble trying to plot my current dataframe. I currently have values like this in the cells of my dataframe:

```
 (test, 5)
```

'test' should be on the x-axis of my plot. The number '5' is the count for the number of times 'test' occurs. Therefore the bar for test should be of height 5.

My dataframe looks something like this (sample):

```
  one           two               three         four          type
(test,5)      (test2, 20)       (test3, 500)   (test4, 2)     company
(notest,89)   (notest2, 220)    (notest, 50)   (notest4, 32)  residental
...
...
```

The title of the first plot from the above df would be 'company'.

I would like to plot each row as a subplot, but I can't think of how I would separate the counts and plot them.

If I was just plotting the 'company' row, I think I would just get a dataframe like this.

```
           test     test2    test3    test4
company     5        20       500       2
```

But because all of the words aren't exactly the same in each row if I did this for all rows then I'd have a lot of null values (which I assume would be empty bars in my plot). The dataframe would probably look like this:

```
             test  test2  test3  test4  notest notest2 notest3 notest4
company       5    20      500     2     NONE   NONE    NONE    NONE 
residental  NONE   NONE   NONE   NONE     89    220     50       32
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if that helps you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfs = []
rows = df.iterrows()
row = next(rows)
# Iterate over all of the rows
for row in df.iterrows():
    name, data = row
    # Create a column by the first item of each tuple
    row_df = pd.DataFrame({x[0]: [x[1]] for x in data if x is not None})
    row_df['type'] = name
    # Set the type as index
    dfs.append(row_df)
# Concatenate all
res_df = pd.concat(dfs).set_index('type')
```

Output:

```
            notest  notest2 notest4 test  test2 test3   test4
type                            
company      NaN      NaN     NaN     5    20     500     2
residental    50      220     32     NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: When I loaded your data I received the tuples as strings so I parsed them. I edited the post and dropped it, it should work for you now.

Comment: It was a variable that was left from the tuples parsing. Changed to `data` in `pd.DataFrame({x[0]: [x[1]] for x in data})`.

Comment: You probably have `None` values in the source dataframe (you did not provide them inside the test case). Added `if x is not None` inside the dict comprehension.

Comment: That is just a warning. It says valuable stuff that you would like to read, but it does not affect your result. Check the value of `res_df`.

Comment: It works according to your test case. You should upload more representing data if you would like us to overcome the challenges in there.

Comment: Upload your output here then.

Answer (score 0):

I would format your data to an array and work with that.

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [('test',5), ('test2', 20), ('test3', 500), ('test4', 2), 'company'],
    [('notest',89), ('notest2', 220), ('notest', 50), ('notest4', 32), 'residental']]
names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'type']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=names)


df = df.set_index('type') 
types = df.index.unique()
xnames = []
yvalues = []

for plot_type in types:
    xname = [values[0] for values in df.loc[plot_type].values]
    yvalue = [values[1] for values in df.loc[plot_type].values]

    xnames.append(xname)
    yvalues.append(yvalue)
```

Output:

```
xnames
[['test', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'],
 ['notest', 'notest2', 'notest', 'notest4']]

yvalues
[[5, 20, 500, 2], [89, 220, 50, 32]]
```